# Can we have bounty filters for the featured questions?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Can we have filters for the featured questions according to their bounty?
The list became a little crowded recently...

**EDIT** I meant filters for +50, +100,... for tags it's fine!

Answer (score 3):

Since I have voiced skeptical opinions about the effectiveness of bounties nowadays, let me also offer a partial existing solution.

```
Filtering by tag seems to be the way to go.
```

Click *featured*. Click your preferece within the list of *Related Tags* on the sidebar (don't pick the tag from the list of your personal favorites, that will overrule *featured*).

I'm a bit ashamed for not realizing this possibility right away.